# min and max produces wrong result in r

Tags: r

I made a dataframe with columns year,month,temp,upper and lower

upper and lower are the max temperature by year and lower is the minimum

I have two questions:

first is why for some values in the end of dataframe the upper and lower are not correctly computed but in the rest of the dataframe they are fine?

And why am I getting weird axes when I am using ggplot 
the dataframe is this

as you can see upper and lower for 2017 is wrong

```
     Year   Month  Temp  upper lower        
1    1880   Jan    -.29  -.29   -.09 
2    1880   Feb    -.18  -.29   -.09
3    1880   Mar    -.11  -.29   -.09
       ......
1655 2017   Nov     .84   .96   1.12
1656 2017   Dec     .88   .96   1.12
```

the code is:

```
 newDF <- df %>%
 group_by(Year) %>%
 mutate(upper = max(Temp), # identify max value for month day
       lower = min(Temp) # identify min value for month day
       ) %>% 
 ungroup()

    p <- ggplot(newDF, aes(Month, Temp)) +
    geom_linerange(newDF, mapping=aes(x=Year, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), colour = "wheat2", alpha=.1)
    print(p)
```

the graph seems fine but the axis are messed up
[image]

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: Your code for me gave the correct minimum and maximum temperature by year for the data you posted. The result of running your posted code on your posted data was `structure(list(Year = c(1880L, 1880L, 1880L, 2017L, 2017L), Month = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Nov"
), class = "factor"), Temp = c(-0.29, -0.18, -0.11, 0.84, 0.88
), upper = c(-0.11, -0.11, -0.11, 0.88, 0.88), lower = c(-0.29, 
-0.29, -0.29, 0.84, 0.84)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're very close -- it's just the second part that needs a tweak. `ggplot` can work with a date field as the x axis, but the `Month` field is text (and it doesn't include the Year). Here I make a new column called `date` that combines them. `lubridate` is a handy package for that, since it does some smart parsing of date formats.

```
# Fake data
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(
  Year = rep(1880:2017, each = 12),
  Month = rep(month.abb, times = (2017-1880+1)),
  Temp = rnorm(n = 1656, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)


newDF = df %>%
  # This line adds a date field based on Year and Month
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(paste(Year, Month, 1))) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(upper = max(Temp), # identify max value for month day
         lower = min(Temp), # identify min value for month day
          ) %>% 
  ungroup()

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(newDF, aes(date, Temp)) +
  geom_linerange(newDF, mapping=aes(x=Year, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), colour = "wheat2", alpha=.1)
print(p)
```

Comment: yes that was the problem and I just changed some columns to numeric.